# Firebase query filtering predicates order dependent & behaving weird

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's assume sample list in database:

[image]

In following snippets, `ref` is:
`var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('test').orderByKey();`

I noticed weird behavior of 2 queries:

1. `ref.limitToFirst(2).endAt('5')`
   It yields `4, 5`, whereas I expected `0, 1`.
   2 things are surprising:

   1. If order of predicates is swapped: `ref.endAt('5').limitToFirst(2)`,
      the result is ok: `0, 1`
   2. result of `ref.limitToLast(2).endAt('5')` is `4, 5` as well.
      Just as expected, but still, `limitToLast()` shouldn't work just the same as `limitToFirst()` here.
2. `ref.limitToLast(2).startAt('5')`
   Similarly yeilds `5, 6`, even if one could expect `8, 9`.
   And similarly to above:

   1. `ref.startAt('5').limitToLast(2)` works fine (`8, 9`)
   2. `ref.limitToFirst(2).startAt('5')` yeilds same result (`5, 6`)

Now, it's either a bug or it's just me not comprehending firebase queries.
Neither documentation nor API reference mentions the importance of the order of predicates.

I'm using Firebase 3.X (3.3.0) for web.
Snipped used to display list of results:

```
ref.once('value').then(function(snap) {
  snap.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key);
  });
});
```

*Sorry for meaningless title. If you have a better idea, submit an edit proposal.*

**Edit:**

`limitTo*()`  predicates were introduced in Firebase 2.0.0. Before them it was just `limit()`.
With only `limit()` and (`startAt()` or `endAt()`) denoting order of selection from the list of results, it could excuse contradicting results above (but **not** queries working ok with predicates swapped).

However, both `startAt()` and `endAt()` can be used simultaneously, so they can't denote the direction (or at least shouldn't).

Let's play:

- `ref.startAt('5').endAt('9').limitToFirst(3)` → `5, 6, 7` - ok
- `ref.startAt('5').endAt('9').limitToLast(3)` → `7, 8, 9` - ok
- `ref.limitToFirst(3).startAt('5').endAt('9')` or `ref.startAt('5').limitToFirst(3).endAt('9')` →
  *Uncaught Error: Query: Can't combine startAt(), endAt(), and **limit()**. Use limitToFirst() or limitToLast() instead.*

:-D
bug I guess.

**Edit 2:**

Just as I thought. From [`limit()` docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/limit.html):

> If combined with startAt(), the query will include the specified number of children after the starting point. If combined with endAt(), the query will include the specified number of children before the ending point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is indeed a bug.  In particular, if you do `limitToLast(...).startAt(...)` or `limitToFirst(...).endAt(...)`, we'll end up reversing the limit and giving incorrect results.

The simple workaround is to always make sure your `limitToXXX()` call is last in your query.  This shouldn't be necessary, but for now will solve the problem.  We'll try to get this fixed in a future release.  Thanks for reporting this!

Answer (score 1):

Actually the error message combined with `limit()` docs gave a little bit of insight into closed Firebase source code:

My bet is on `limitTo*()` still falling back to depreciated `limit()`'s implementation if predicates are applied in specific order. If that order is changed; a different, possibly newer and correct implementation is used.
That could explain all inconsistencies and problems demonstrated in my question.

*Sorry for answering my own question, but I came up with this only after some thinking (and playing!).

Already submitted a ticket to Firebase, they will probably answer here.*